# List<List<List<Float>>> Parse though polygon object

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, polygon

I am trying to parse through a Polygon object to get each of the latitude and longitude but having trouble iterating though it. I am developing in Kotlin Android Studio IDE.

```
[
   [
       [-119.81009614166666, 39.52721586111111],
       [-119.81022475833333, 39.527206336111114],
       [-119.81007891388889, 39.52602547777778],
       [-119.8099503, 39.526035005555556],
       [-119.81009614166666, 39.52721586111111]
   ]
]
```

Comment: _"but having trouble iterating through it."_ what're issues you're facing? Can you please [edit] and elaborate on them? And also don't forget to include [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If your coordinates is in the format above, do the following steps:

```
var firstCoord = coordinates[0][0]
Log.i("firstCoord", firstCoord.toString());
```

Log statement gives you the first coordinates: [-119.8101, 39.527214]

Not to sure why some of the precision is lost.